# How many ways to form $p$ committees of $q$ members out of $r$ mathematicians such that all committees are unique

Tags: combinatorics

I have been struggling with the general case of this problem, but I was first trying to get a solution for the $p=5 \ q=3 \ r=6$ case, which I know to be $15504$. One person can be in multiple committees. Restrictions are $q<r$ and no two committees consist of the same members, and I think there will be a restriction on $p$ that is clear from a closed-form.

In choosing my first committing, I can choose any $q$, $C_1={{r}\choose{q}}$. In my next committee, I cannot choose the same as $C_1$, but can choose any others, $C_2={{r}\choose{q}}-1$. From here I can see inductively that in my $k$th committee, there are $k-1$ committees that I cannot choose. Combining these,
$$\text{Total(p)}={{r}\choose{q}}({{r}\choose{q}}-1)({{r}\choose{q}}-2)({{r}\choose{q}}-3) \ ... \ ({{r}\choose{q}}-(p-1))$$

In the example case, I get $1860480$, which is grossly off. I would be most interested in why my approach derailed, but if an answer has a better way of thinking about the problem, it would also be great to see that.

Comment: You’ve got $\binom{r}{q}$ possible committees, and you want to know the number of ways to choose $p$ among them? Note that $15504=1860480/5!$.

Comment: $15504$ is $20\choose5$. $20$ is $6\choose3$.

Comment: WTF does it mean for a committee to be "unique"??? I think you mean "all committees are different".

Answer (score 0):

Gathering what was said in comments,
$$\text{Total(p)}=\frac{{{r}\choose{q}}({{r}\choose{q}}-1)({{r}\choose{q}}-2)({{r}\choose{q}}-3) \ ... \ ({{r}\choose{q}}-(p-1))}{p!}$$ as I used the choose operator to prohibit permutations of groups, but overlooked  perumutations of commitees assigned, which turned out to be a roundabout way of generating a binomial coefficient.

Comment: $=\binom{\binom rq}p$, the number of ways you can choose $p$ **different** committees out of the set of all possible committees of size $q$.